# Hard question about computing a real integral using residue thereom

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was asked to consider the integral

$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^4}dx$$

I have spent a lot on this problem and I will show what I have tried so far.

First I complexified $$g(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^4}$$ and will take the real part of the integral after.

The contour is just the upper semicircle, the roots of which that lie enclosed are $$w=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$ and $$w^{3}=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Then I computed the residues to be $(1/4)e^{iw}w^{-3}$ and $(1/4)e^{iw^3}w^{-9}$
But I am really stuck in getting in a nice form. Wolfram evaluates it to be numerically 1.544.

Any idea the best way to simplify?

I am confused because I dont have much experience making our new function something that is only equal if we take the real part, so I dont know when to apply it. There isnt much I can add, I really have spent about 3 hours simply trying to get this one result and I cant do it.

By the way, I really have tried most of the tricks suggested. The problem is that I cant get in numerically or in the form wolfram has it. THAT is what I am looking for someone to help explain

Comment: exactly the same question was asked some weeks ago, sniff around in the complex analysis tag and you will find it

Comment: I tried that, i cant find it

Comment: You can write it as $\frac{-\sqrt 2}{4}i[\sin {\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}+\cos{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}]e^{-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}$

Comment: @MattG88  Write what as that? That isnt the same value as the solution, the answer is a strictly real number

Comment: The sum of residues is going to be something like $-\pi i(w\cos w + iw\cos w^3)/2$. To calculate the real and imaginary part just use the expression $\cos z = (e^{iz} + e^{-iz})/2$, at the end you will have a closed expression with factors like $e^{1/\sqrt{2}}$, $e^{3/\sqrt{2}}$, $\cos(1/\sqrt{2})$, $\cdots$

Comment: @quality Then you must multiply for $2\pi i$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ because i used the real part in solving the integral

Comment: Note that $w^4 = -1$ and that $\overline{w} = 1/w$.  Using that I see your second quantity is just the conjugate of the first.

Comment: @tired  Are you sure it is there?

Comment: yes i think so..

Comment: @tired  Well if you possibly could find it then you could mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have from the residue theorem

$$\begin{align}
\text{Re}\left(\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z^4+1}\,dz\right)&=\text{Re}\left(2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^4+1}, z=e^{i\pi/4}, e^{i3\pi/4}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{ie^{i\pi/4}}}{4e^{i3\pi/4}}+ \frac{e^{ie^{i3\pi/4}}}{4e^{i9\pi/4}}\right)\right) \tag 1\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\frac{ \pi }{2}\left(e^{i\left(\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt2}-\frac\pi4\right)}+e^{i\left(\frac{(-1+i)}{\sqrt2}+\frac\pi4\right)}\right)\right) \tag 2\\\\
&=\pi e^{-\sqrt 2/2}\cos(\pi/4-\sqrt2/2)\\\\
&\approx 1.54427600961814 
\end{align}$$

in agreement with WA!

---

**NOTE:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we made use of the fact that $ie^{-i3\pi/4}=e^{-i\pi/4}$ and $ie^{-i9\pi/4}=e^{i\pi/4}$.